# mysqli query gets syntax error but phpmyadmin works

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

While the following query works with phpmyadmin, when I use mysqli->query(), a syntax error occurs

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT Value INTO @Increment FROM SystemConfiguration WHERE `Key` = 'POIncrement' FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE SystemConfiguration SET Value = Value + @Increment WHERE `Key` = 'POID';
COMMIT;
```

The syntax error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Value INTO @Increment FROM SystemConfiguration WHERE `Key` = 'POIncrement' at line 2
```

Is it that mysqli prepares the query and adds something in?

Comment: mysqli query only accepts one query at a time,transaction or not, use mysqli_multi_query. https://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = <<<SQL
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT Value 
    INTO @Increment 
    FROM SystemConfiguration 
        WHERE `Key` = 'POIncrement' FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE SystemConfiguration 
    SET Value = Value + @Increment 
    WHERE `Key` = 'POID';
COMMIT;
SQL;

$res = mysqli_multi_query($connection, $sql);
```